# how to solve auto logout in 14.04 trusty

Tags: ati, xorg, screen, radeon

when i login to my desktop through lightdm or gdm any time i get logout every time

also on startup from cli when i startx it just keep flash white and black screen for almost 5 minutes

but when i get to login desktop screen please see first line for the problem

i have doubt on my display driver
link for

log 0
http://m.uploadedit.com/b043/141841676692.txt

log 1
http://m.uploadedit.com/b043/1418417336650.txt

i also little messed up .Xauthority and reconfigured with default
please help me getting my desktop working it was fresh install and it's been 3 day's i couldn't fix it my self

thankx in advance